# UI Locks Up even with performSelectorOnMainThread and waitUntilDone:NO

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my `viewController`, I have a timer that fires every 20 seconds and calls a location update. then, when the location is updated, I call a method via `performSelectorOnMainThread`. For some reason, even though I have included `waitUntilDone:NO`, my user interface keeps locking up while the check is performed. Does anyone know how I can improve this so that the screen does not freeze up every 20 seconds? Thank you!

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 20.0 target: self 
    selector: @selector(callAfterSixtySecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

    //other code
}

-(void) callAfterSixtySecond:(NSTimer*) t {

    locationManagerProfile.delegate = self;
    locationManagerProfile.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
    [locationManagerProfile startUpdatingLocation];  
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation 
*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(buttonUpdate) withObject:nil 
        waitUntilDone:NO];   
    }
}
```

**Lastly, my interface is updated with this method:**

```
-(void) buttonUpdate {

    [locationManagerProfile stopUpdatingLocation];
    NSString *userLatitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
    getUserLatitude];
    NSString *userLongitude =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate 
    getUserLongitude];

    NSString *placeLatitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"savedLatitude"];

    NSString *placeLongitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"savedLongitude"];

    NSString *distanceURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.website.com/page.php?
    lat1=%@&lon1=%@&lat2=%@&lon2=%@",userLatitude, userLongitude, placeLatitude, 
    placeLongitude];

    NSData *distanceURLResult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
    URLWithString:distanceURL]];

    NSString *distanceInFeet = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:distanceURLResult 
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([distanceInFeet isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button A" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionA)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGo;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor 
        colorWithRed:44.0/255.0 green:160.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];  
        UIBarButtonItem *btnGoTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button B" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionB)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGoTwo; 
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnGo, 
        btnGoTwo, nil];
    }
    if ([distanceInFeet isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        UIBarButtonItem *btnGo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button C" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionC)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGo;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor 
        colorWithRed:44.0/255.0 green:160.0/255.0 blue:65.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];        
        UIBarButtonItem *btnGoTwo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button B" 
        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionB)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnGoTwo;   
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnGo, 
        btnGoTwo, nil];
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*viewDidLoad* gets called on the main thread, you're adding the timer here so the selector is called on the main thread. You aren't in background. There are many ways to make the method execute concurrently, for example you can call *dispatch_async* inside it:

```
-(void) callAfterSixtySecond:(NSTimer*) t {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, ^{
        locationManagerProfile.delegate = self;
        locationManagerProfile.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
        [locationManagerProfile startUpdatingLocation];  
    });
}
```

Or add the timer asynchronously:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, ^{
        NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 20.0 target: self 
        selector: @selector(callAfterSixtySecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    });

    //other code
}
```

Comment: thanks! I am getting an error that says passing void(^)(void) to paramater of incompatible type 'unsigned long'. any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are fetching some data from a URL using `dataWithContentsOfURL:` while on the main thread.

That looks like it would be responsible for the freeze.

Try moving that out so you only call to the main thread when the data you want to present in the UI is ready.

Answer (score 3):

The idea with `CLLocationManager` is that you create, configure and start it once when your app becomes interested in the location. Then, based on the configuration you set, it will call you back (`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` or, better if you can, `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`) whenever the location is changed. Repeatedly starting and stopping the location manager is inefficient and is unlikely to get you accurate location information.

Once you resolve that you'll probably be ok.

After that, you need to brush up on threading as the timer will be firing on the main thread, so switching back to the main thread does't really change anything (just adds a short delay).

Also, don't write so much code. Particularly if it's the same code over and over again. For instance, if you want to get multiple things from user defaults, don't do:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"savedLatitude"]
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"savedLongitude"]
```

Better to do:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
[defaults stringForKey:@"savedLatitude"]
[defaults stringForKey:@"savedLongitude"]
```

(user defaults is just an example, this applies to any method call you're making multiple times for no reason...)

It's a small gain each time but it all adds up (both to runtime cost and readability / maintenance).

Comment: The answer from Seán Labastille is also an excellent point and will contribute to the issue.

Comment: Using [NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] or assigning it to a variable will have the same memory address and doesn't cost anything to memory stack, it just becomes personal preference. Do you want extra lines of code, or slightly longer lines.

Comment: @BillBurgess `[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]` might not be the best example, but as a general rule the approach is valid as it will avoid the cost of whatever processing the accessor method does.

Answer (score 2):

When the timer callback is called, you're in the main thread. Then when you call the buttonUpdate method using "performSelectorOnMainThread" you simply queue this message in the main run loop and continue execution. Then when it is time for buttonUpdate to be executed, it blocks the UI due to the synchronous network call "dataWithContentsOfURL" run inside the main thread. 
The best way to fix your issue is to call "buttonUpdate" immediately (don't use performSelectorOnMainThread as you are already in the main thread) and call your initWithURL from within a GCD async or an NSOperationQueue. While waiting for the data to be updated you can show an "updating message" in the button and as soon as your async block or concurrent NSOperation terminates you can finally update the button to its final state (don't forget to do the update on the main thread).